# How can I make this Bassline like Boris Brejcha

Tags: electronic-music

Help me figure out how Boris is able to make this type of bassline.

Please include instrument suggestions and effects.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start with a saw wave. Then you have to modulate a low pass filter over it. Possibly with LFO or through manual automation.

Then you need EQ and a distortion VST after the filter. That is my opinion. In fact if I was trying to reproduce this sound I would reach for the VST called CamelCrusher.

Lastly, you can tell there is a very wide stereo field, so use your best stereo widener and/or chorus effect.

I would probably start with Tal chorus.

Good luck.